# How to give a span or div the smallest size that will just fit its text content?

Tags: css, fonts

For example, in this simulated rendering, the orange background indicates the extents of the enclosing `span` or `div` element that *just* encloses all the contained text:

[image]

If that's too much to hope for, then a second best would be something like this:

[image]

In this second case the locations of the top and bottom edges coincide with the text's [baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_%28typography%29) and [mean line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_line).

At the absolute very least, I'd love to learn how to *reliably* line up the bottom of a `span` or `div` so that it is perfectly flush against the text's baseline.  Even this seemingly straightforward task is beyond my reach.  (My success rate is about 50%, and AFAICT entirely random.)

---

Below I show my best attempts so far.  My results are terrible for the most part.  It is true that for one font I get pretty close to the second case shown above, but I suspect this is just a lucky coincidence, judging by how poorly the same CSS fares with other fonts.

---

**Code snippet below (or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/368rncca/)).  Click on Full Page for best results.**

```css
* { vertical-align: baseline !important; }

#root  { padding: 20px; }
td     { padding: 0px; }

.monospace    { font-family: monospace; }
.proportional { font-family: tangerine; }

.ground     { padding: 10px; }
.ground > * { margin: 10px; }
.ground > * { font-size: 50px; }
.ground > * { background: orange; }
.ground > * { display: inline-block; }

.tweak-heights
.ground   * { height: 1ex; }
.tweak-heights
.ground   * { line-height: 0; }
.tweak-heights
.ground > * { margin: 20px 10px; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">

<div id="root">
<div style="display: block; width: 100%; text-align: right;"><div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 50px 0 0;">(Click on FULL PAGE for best results.)</div></div>

    <table>
        <tr><td>
<div class="ground">
    <span class="q monospace">Smallest SPAN&nbsp;0123456789</span><br/>
    <span class="q proportional">Smallest SPAN&nbsp;0123456789</span><br/>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td class="tweak-heights">
<div class="ground">
    <span class="q monospace">Smallest SPAN&nbsp;0123456789</span><br/>
    <span class="q proportional">Smallest SPAN&nbsp;0123456789</span><br/>
        </td></tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: That's not how fonts are supposed to work so any solution is likely to be typeface and font-size dependant. Not recommended . I wonder what *actual* issue you are really trying to resolve.

Comment: As per @Paulie_D's comment, this sounds like an [XY problem statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what you are trying to do that requires you to (at least, according to you based on not yet mentioned information) get the text bounding box based on the inkbox, rather than the font-indicated bounds?